# Argument of type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: typescript

I have a number of functions that I'm trying to call with the purpose of formatting an input-value. They have in common that they are getting called with just one argument.

```js
// return-type of formatters is string | ('yes' | 'no')
const formatters = {
  bool: (value: boolean) => value ? 'yes' : 'no',
  currency: (value: string) => value,
  percent: (value: number) => value.toString(),
  //...
}
```

Also, they have some `undefined`- and `null`-checks in common. Hence, I was thinking to use a `Proxy`:

```js
// proxies all render-methods with undefined- and null-check
const proxiedFormatters = () => new Proxy(formatters, handler);
```

The `handler` is causing me headaches though:

```js
const handler: ProxyHandler<typeof formatters> = {
  get: function (target: typeof formatters, property: keyof typeof formatters) {
    return (value: string | number | boolean | undefined | null) => {
      if (value === undefined) return value;
      if (value === null) return "-";
      const formatFn = target[property];
      // Argument of type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
      return formatFn.bind(target)(value);
    };
  },
};
```

From what I understand is that TS is telling me that the intersection `'string | number | boolean'` is not possible, hence the expected `never`-type. Any idea how to do this properly?

Comment: You've run into [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended approach is to refactor to use generic indexed accesses into a mapped type, as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  For the example code here, [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mqYRjm) shows the recommended refactoring.  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That looks 100% like what I'm looking for, though it's not that easy to read/understand. I'd definitely accept your answer if you wrote one up!

Comment: It seems like the return type of the functions is not considered properly, I'm adding it to my question to clarify it a bit.

Comment: How would you like for it to be considered?  I can add typings for the returns like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mA8RRN) but TS's typing for proxies doesn't consider possible mutation of the target type (like whatever you're doing with `"-"` instead of `null`).  And that really seems out of scope for the question.  How should I proceed?

Comment: Like this should be fine https://shorturl.at/aghpN

Comment:  `string | ("yes" | "no")` is just `string`. Can I just write `string` in my answer? You can use `string | ("yes" | "no")` in your own code, but here it's just a distraction.

Comment: Okay I'll write up my answer when I get a chance; might be a few hours

Comment: No hurry, I started using your solution already, it's working for me :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that your `get` implementation isn't really type safe, since the returned function allows `value` to be the full `string | number | boolean | undefined | null` [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) even though it should only accept the input (or `undefined | null` I guess) for the particular `property`.  Observe: first, let me modify your `formatters` functions so they actually care about the types of the parameters:

```
const formatters = {
  bool: (value: boolean) => value ? 'yes' : 'no',
  currency: (value: string) => value.toUpperCase(),
  percent: (value: number) => value.toFixed(2),
}
```

Then with your implementation:

```
const h = {
  get: function (target: typeof formatters, property: keyof typeof formatters) {
    return (value: string | number | boolean | undefined | null) => {
      if (value === undefined) return value;
      if (value === null) return "-";
      const formatFn = target[property];
      return formatFn.bind(target)(value); // error
    };
  },
};
```

The compiler happily lets you call something that would blow up at runtime:

```
h.get(formatters, "percent")("oops"); // <-- no compiler error, but
//  RUNTIME ERROR  value.toFixed is not a function
```

This is the first-order reason why there's a compiler error in `formatFn.bind(target)(value)`. The compiler is telling you that it can't be sure that `value` is applicable to `formatFn.bind(target)`; the only way it *could* be sure is if `value` were a valid input for *every possible* `formatFn`, which means it would need to be a `boolean`, a `string`, *and* a `number` at the same type, or `boolean & string & number`.  There is no such value that works this way, so the compiler reduces that [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).

(Of course since you're assigning `h` to `ProxyHandler<typeof formatters>`, you won't have an opportunity to call it that way, but that's out of scope here, since discussing typings for `Proxy` objects could fill another book-length answer.)

---

So you really want to make your handler [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` of `property` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof typeof formatters`, and then have the returned function only accept the correct input:

```
type Formatters = typeof formatters; 

const h = {
  get: function <K extends keyof Formatters>(target: Formatters, property: K) {
    return (value: Parameters<Formatters[K]>[0] | undefined | null) => {
      if (value === undefined) return value;
      if (value === null) return "-";
      const formatFn = target[property];
      return formatFn.bind(target)(value); // still error!
    };
  },
};

h.get(formatters, "percent")("oops"); // compiler error!
// ------------------------> ~~~~~~
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

Now `value` has to be the parameter type for the formatter with key `K`, using [the `Parameters` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype).  And so a caller will be warned if they call the wrong thing, hooray!

But... there's *still* an error inside the implementation.  And that's because even though it's now type safe, the compiler still can't see it.  It doesn't understand the correlation between `Formatters[K]` and `Parameters<Formatters[K]>[0]` for generic `K`.  For any *specific* `K`, like `"bool"`, the compiler could see the connection.  But when `K` is generic, the type `Parameters<Formatters[K]>[0]` is a generic [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), and the compiler essentially cannot reason abstractly about those.

This is more or less the topic of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), which talks about correlated *union* types, but the same problem exists with correlated *generic conditional* types.

---

The recommended fix is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The compiler is better at reasoning about generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  If we can refactor the types so that they represent mappings over a very basic key-value utility type, and indexes into such mappings, the compiler will be happier.  We want `formatFn` to be of a type like `(value: XXX) => string` and `value` to be of type `XXX` (or `XXX | null | undefined`), where `XXX` are *identical* generic type functions of `K`.

Here's one way.

We want our utility type to look like

```
interface FormatValue {
    bool: boolean;
    currency: string;
    percent: number;
}
```

and then the type of `formatters` is:

```
type Formatters = { [K in keyof FormatValue]: (value: FormatValue[K]) => string; }

const formatters: Formatters = {
  bool: (value: boolean) => value ? 'yes' : 'no',
  currency: (value: string) => value.toUpperCase(),
  percent: (value: number) => value.toString(),
  //...
} // okay
```

So instead of writing the opaque-to-the-compiler `Parameters<Formatters[K]>[0]`, we can just look up `FormatValue[K]`, and `Formatters` itself is a mapped type over `FormatValue`.  That makes the following compile as intended:

```
const handler: ProxyHandler<Formatters> = {
  get: function <K extends keyof Formatters>(target: Formatters, property: K) {
    return (value: FormatValue[K] | undefined | null) => {
      if (value === undefined) return value;
      if (value === null) return "-";
      const formatFn = target[property];
      return formatFn.bind(target)(value); // okay!
    };
  },
};
```

`formatFn` is seen as type `(value: FormatValue[K]) => string`, and `value` is narrowed to `FormatValue[K]` by the time you call it. Those are identical types, and so the compiler allows the call.

For more details about this technique, read through microsoft/TypeScript#47109.

---

So that's the basic approach.  Still it forces you to write out that `FormatValue` utility type yourself and then redundantly define `formatters`, writing out the key names and value types twice, and if you modify `formatters` you have to manually modify `FormatValue` to keep it in sync.

That's okay, but if you'd rather have the compiler *compute* `FormatValue` from `formatters`, you can do so.  First, rename `formatters` out of the way, so that we can have the compiler infer its type:

```
const _formatters = {
  bool: (value: boolean) => value ? 'yes' : 'no',
  currency: (value: string) => value.toUpperCase(),
  percent: (value: number) => value.toString(),
  //...
}
```

Then `FormatValue` can be written in terms of `typeof _formatters`:

```
type FormatValue = { [K in keyof typeof _formatters]: 
  Parameters<typeof _formatters[K]>[0] }
```

And `Formatters` is still a mapped type over `FormatValue`:

```
type Formatters = { [K in keyof FormatValue]: (value: FormatValue[K]) => string; }
```

And we can just assign `_formatters` to a value `formatters` of type `Formatters`:

```
const formatters: Formatters = _formatters;
```

Now if `_formatters` changes, everything will update itself automatically:

```
const _formatters = {
  bool: (value: boolean) => value ? 'yes' : 'no',
  currency: (value: string) => value.toUpperCase(),
  percent: (value: number) => value.toString(),
  date: (value: Date) => value.toLocaleDateString() // added
  //...
}

type FormatValue = { [K in keyof typeof _formatters]: Parameters<typeof _formatters[K]>[0] }
/* type FormatValue = {
  bool: boolean;
  currency: string;
  percent: number;
  date: Date; // magically appears
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-RmR0s2bB+Szarh7WLbg0VzM+SrLKXDRu54SN6quoNbiq-2q5QwKB5sVIAD0ZaQAB51erSOwlmAYHQSQTxJ8aItZiERPB1hp2zDJUsuMYshh2AwB+ELBXRZy+oMRqMkHRJL5eCB9odjsAuws4XqVqtTKNW+oAAqfIauAASp9bVZBECBaahUGsMlW0cIQXmv7kMhoDgRAkGKQQIngbgABUbggAAhXRuAAZSOBkABF2GgRoAHVBF+BMRxWN8Xg2WEtmJZp4kMZQSVMJkWkcFx3CgTxvF8AJh1CcJImiKjOTRWMMVSKx52yXICjqUpykqSNgmzSI9gDVo8S6USWj6VDkinaYdXLMsskM-cAPkZ8kH6R5IVI004NfSz0ygRYj14dYZHI4JLnUPgDig3dqwAaSQCAhjEYBRkkf5AXuCyIQcywNF9XZ1Bip53zea1vhiJB-KHPSSBdGUBKQC9znAXYXirFKrIkC1-LtSwLQABjtQk+WpYBaRxBUmXcp1pWUuUZDagUhV2EUWjDFl+sY7kZG6pUxpVJANS1Yd5Gch5YuNDZEu4K1Pkyh01udRbXXsj0vTChLzj9ZSg30xI0IwILwkEABCY7Q2HCMux-Uy40IkgkxTEiM2WhTGjzDQCy+Yt7rndt3uHOda1RtH0YxtHrAAP1xvHkcrABBC52kUpAgTM5x0RSTw13rTcoCgRhQAUElgQbOAaDKqFyfuSm2g6cRnCyLse24PtNEHQGiLHCcpylucNNyJdaTpjckC3byd04Yy-wPEggIoUCl1kfXWA2gB9UHJDc4dKMK-QaOMej1NlJw3A8LwXA4uT1rCCIoiy5TBO0hjegkwoSjKCpdK2CGlNRXFBZoMOF1yLThNk4dRhEBJg6QdDc9T8T2AAGXYdASULsQM5SSoCcMkW4X-Uy4PM+yADVZTcpBatXZFIop2z7it+z3ztS9Ssgd8n2HpBR9i99avqpqWpb1gywAKmBNuqu4LvOTIu3aKdujgEmth-d4rLqYYC-3nEHN1AF-F75zsR1GriBJu7Tey0WGMu8x7WTwL3QKGIkCD2ip3eIE8HYJD3gffQy8mS31LOvNgywDTAIkMlHBNt57Wz+ubLBawHziEvNeO85CaCVXwZ+aWnlty+ROFWQKwVQrhUgQCIEe93zxV2ngxeLx0oHVtFlHK0t8qnXgUIp4SCIDL1amFfkHUVxdV0AyHqx0SDTW7jyYaajRqIiWhNHRq52QzXlJoxUBUVr33WqQtM21TQ3UtBlcRR08onRMWdLawBPTemuuabg-oWhBk+vfH6zdiEkDnNaIYdBoAawZAtFRNB1TT1WOwLhAB3Og3B1iGLGHWU8uIGTqj7BAeAvwnKkISUk0YfCQGVFEh1XJxUqEaAXqlERZCwqtgiSZJA-4iCzCAA)

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this detailed explanation. Highly appreciated! Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!!