# How can I set a value with dynamic key with typescript?

Tags: typescript

This is my item-type:

```
export type DimArgument = { id: string, label: string, defaultValue: number };
```

I want to have a generic function that will update this item, with a key and value arguments:

```
        const changeHandler = (
          field: keyof DimArgument,
          value: string
        ) => {
          dimArgument[field] = value;  // <-- ERROR HERE!
```

But I get an error on the last line:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322) (parameter)
> field: keyof DimArgument

How can I do it without errors?

thanks

Comment: what is the definition of `item`?

Comment: item has a type of DimArgument. I updated the var value so it will be more clear

Comment: Somewhat related: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76188330/typescript-union-type-of-functions-weirdly-becomes-an-intersection-type-of-the-a) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76110985/argument-of-type-string-number-boolean-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-t/), because `keyof DimArgument` is a union, but the intersection of the possible values is `never`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are statically specifying the type of the value `string`, however, `DimArgument` also has `number` in it. Thus, when you try to set the value for the `keyof DimArgument` you get `string & number`, which results in `never`. To fix it you have to add a generic parameter for the `field` and get the type of that field exactly:

```
type DimArgument = { id: string; label: string; defaultValue: number };
const dimArgument = {} as DimArgument;

const changeHandler = <K extends keyof DimArgument>(
  field: K,
  value: DimArgument[K],
) => {
  dimArgument[field] = value; 
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAiBLAtgQSgcwFctgA7eAXjgG84MATALjgGcYoNT8BuOAGwCGAI2B9mbDl171gAMwGE+MAGoC+hYM1LERUOAF9uAKADGEUmzj1seIiXJwq1fXAEt0NgsTIxjp85YmABYCXMAAEqH0fMB6VAA8ANJwoDBk9O4A1sCIELIeuF72MAB8ABRGcHCyGKJMcIkANJVwAG5qGsyYhXY+ANqJALrNAJSOJTQt1j3e5H01dYOObR3AvEaGRkA)